# Custom NaveMesh movement and rotation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding, navmesh

I don't find anything useful which implement custom movement and rotation for NavMesh in Unity. I don't want to use steering part of `Nav Mesh Agent` component but I want to use NavMesh obstacle avoidance and pathfinding.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correct, you want to limit your characters movement with a NavMesh instead of using colliders.

For example, I have a **robot** on a hill which I control with arrow buttons and I don't want it to fall down off a cliff.

In my case, my character had the `Character Controller` component. All I had to do was to add the `Nav Mesh Agent` component to my character, **alongside** the `Character Controller` component.

**Important!** Ground your character stands on should still have a `Collider` of any kind, like a `Box Collider`, because when I disabled the Box Collider attached to the ground, my character wasn't able to move but you don't need to attach colliders to your obstacles. Making them `Navigation Static` and baking the `NavMesh` does the trick.

**I did not implement any extra code regarding the `Nav Mesh Agent` component. My RobotController.cs did just fine.**

The variables under the **Steering** section of the `Nav Mesh Agent` like `Speed`, `Angular Speed` & `Acceleration` does not override the ones I implemented on my RobotController script.

**Summary**

My character has components:

- `Character Controller`
- `RobotController.cs`
- `Nav Mesh Agent`

in this order and RobotController.cs is as simple as this:

```
if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
  if(speed < maxVelocity)
    speed += acceleration * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
  else
    speed = maxVelocity; 
}

velocity.x = (transform.forward * speed).x;
velocity.z = (transform.forward * speed).z;
```

Comment: I forgot to tell that my character move by mouse clicking. So there are some obstacles in middle of path and it should avoid them. Because of that I use NavMesh. Also I want to use it for AI in the game too. The thing which I don't figure it out is how I should know next position which according to that rotate character. I want my character rotate to the next in direct point then move and when the direction change rotate to it and this process is continued until reach the point.

Comment: I really don't know the exact way but I think you can do that with `Coroutine()`. For example: First rotate your character manually by  (without using `Nav Mesh Agent`) then assign the target of your `Nav Mesh Agent`. You should check out [Coroutine()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html) & [LookRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html)

Comment: It can't be possible by `Coroutine` or `LookRotation` because for example assume maze path, because I don't have for example corner points so I can't calculate direction for change its rotation. By having clicked point it does't help.